# Why is the variable String type, even though I converted it to int?

Tags: java, bluej, parseint

The variable int g is supposed to be a int, but on output it is being taken as a String, can't figure out what's wrong.

```
class scantest
    {
        public static int String_to_Int(String a)       
        {
            int n=Integer.parseInt(a);
            return n;
        }
        public static int brooh()
        {
            String a="43";
           int s=String_to_Int(a);
            return s;
        }
        public static void main()
        {
            int g=brooh();
            System.out.println(g +"\n" +g+1);
        }
    }
```

****Output****

```
43
431
```

Comment: `g +"\n" +g` is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All arithmetic (in your case `+`) inside of a `System.out.println` statement, must be done INSIDE parenthesis.

Your print statement would look like this:

```
System.out.println(g +"\n" + (g+1));
```

Note that `g+1` is inside parenthesis

Comment: It should be noted that this isn't something that's magically different inside `System.out.println`: those are general rules that apply to string concatenation in any context. So `String s = g + "\n" + g + 1` would face the same issue.

Comment: It is even more basic than that. Think operator precedence.

Comment: No problem! Mark this as the accepted answer and make sure to read the other comment left as it provides a bit more insight :)